# Can't figure out why ng-repeat not sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML which I which I would like to sort reverse chronologically by the newestComment:

```
<div class="list list-inset"
    ng-repeat="(threadId, thread) in messageThreads | orderBy:'thread.newestComment'"
    ng-if="thread.newestComment > messageClearTime">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        {{thread.newestComment}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The data (messageThreads) is this with the threadId as the key and the newestComment as a timestamp:

```
{ "5381897" : {
      "newestComment" : 1403280014,
      "title" : "asdf"
    },
  "5595015" : {
      "newestComment" : 1403192555,
      "title" : ""
    },
  "5761260" : {
      "newestComment" : 1403126044,
      "title" : ""
    },
  "5838498" : {
      "newestComment" : 1403279962,
      "title" : "Share Test"
    }
}
```

No matter what I do I can't seem to figure out how to make it sort--it always just comes out in the order the array is in. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `orderBy` filter only works on arrays of objects, not on objects themselves. See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).